# How to read a particular field from comma separated text file line using c#

Tags: c#

I saw many post here but all are telling about how to read a text file line by line..
but i dont want line by line, i want to read a line field by field.

Example of my text file is following

Accepted, 2013/02/22, 20:12, ss123, 1234,1234,1234,Failed*Some reason ,20,500
Rejected, 2013/02/22, 20:12, ss123, 1234,1234,1234,Failed*Some reason ,20,500

output text file i want like:

Accepted, 2013/02/22, 20:12, ss123, 1234,1234,1234,Accepted,20,500

Rejected, 2013/02/22, 20:12, ss123, 1234,1234,1234,Some reason ,20,500

in the above out put example, first i need to check if the line contains Accepted or not, if it contains Accepted then i need to replace 8th column(Failed*Some reason) with Accepted otherwise i need write only reason in 8th column(Some reason) why it is Rejected..
thanks in advance if u could solve my problem...

I am thinking do like following code..anybuddy plz help me..
    enter code here

```
try

{

 System.IO.TextReader ReadFile = new StreamReader("c:\\ATMLOG.txt");

 System.IO.TextWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter("c:\\DeatailReport.txt");

string line = ReadFile.ReadLine()

while(line!=null)
{

if(line.contains("Accepted")
{

string[] strArr = line.Split(',');
strArr[8]="Accepted";//i wanted to replace 8th column of comma separated text file line with Accepted 
TextWrite.writeln(line);
}
else

{

switch(strArr[8])
{
case "some reasson" : //which reason will be mached that should be write on 8th column of comma separated text file

case "some reasson":

; 
;
;



}

            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: following code is not working:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get an array of fields with `String.Split()`

```
string[] strArr = myStr.Split(',');
```

Comment: @user2448680 do you have some sample code that I can copy and paste so that I might be able to run it through a debugger?

Comment: yeah i have some kind code that i will upload..thank u for response:)

Comment: @user2448680 so where's that line: `string Status = strArr[7];` that you mentioned?

Comment: previously i was thinking to store 8th column in one string variable and compare that variable with some predefined reasons..

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't even bother with performing the split. Since it appears everything is `Failed*Some Reason` and you simply need `Failed*` to disappear, I'd perform a replace:

```
line = line.Replace("Failed*", "");
```

To make it slightly more efficient you could still check for `Accepted`.

```
if (!line.Contains("Accepted"))
{
    line = line.Replace("Failed*", "");
}
```

Comment: i wanted to replace "Failed*Some reason" with Accepted but reason is always different..

Comment: That doesn't really match what you described in your question under  the output text. Your example indicates you simply want `Failed*` to go away. Perhaps if you elaborate a little more on various expected outputs that would not be met by this answer, I will look at the answer's shortcomings a little more closely.

Comment: actually i am trying to read a ATM log files which is generated automatically and trying to filter that log file and producing Detail report text file.  which will be having Accepted or Rejected check details. Rejected checks having the reason why that is rejected and that reason i used to compare with my predefined reasons if it matched then i used write that reason on that field.

Comment: @user2448680: That really doesn't clear anything up or explain what the 2 submitted answers lack.

Comment: yeah that second submitted answer is right but it will work for only Accepted line,but for Rejected reason i have to check with predefined reasons that is the problem ...thanks for response..:)